# JavaFX How to position the Mouse

Tags: javafx, position, mouse

I am trying to make a little game and in the most games the mouse gets locked in the center of the screen. So, is it possible to **lock** the mouse in the center of the screen or **set** the position of the mouse in JavaFX? I know that it is possible to do, and I also know some samples written in LWJGL or just with the AWT/SWING package.

Thanks for help.

Comment: 1)In Swing you can do this using Robot,an example here:http://programmersheaven.com/discussion/306819/can-i-move-cursor-in-java 2)Maybe making the mouse transparent is a solution for you?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same, please share a solution if you've found one

Comment: @GoXr3Plus Thank you for responding, but sadly the MouseTransparency is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You want to move the mouse programmatically in javaFX?That's the whole point?

Comment: @GoXr3Plus well, yes I'm trying to, as said, "set" the position of the Mouse while the transpareny only causes to disable the MouseEvents on the Node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 11/27/2019**

From now you can use also **JavaFX Robot API**:
https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html

---

Here is the code you need:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MoveCursor extends Application {

Scene scene;
VBox container;
Button moveMouse;
Button showHideCursor;
public static int screenWidth = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();
public static int screenHeight = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    // MoveMouse Button
    moveMouse = new Button("Move Cursor to the center of Screen");
    moveMouse.setOnAction(m -> {
        moveCursor(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
    });

    // ShowHide Cursor
    showHideCursor = new Button("Show/Hide Cursor");
    showHideCursor.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    showHideCursor.setOnAction(m -> {
        if (scene.getCursor() != Cursor.NONE)
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
        else
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    });

    // Container
    container = new VBox();
    container.getChildren().addAll(moveMouse, showHideCursor);

    // Scene
    scene = new Scene(container, 500, 500);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * Move the mouse to the specific screen position
 * 
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
public void moveCursor(int screenX, int screenY) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(screenX, screenY);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: awesome! I didn't knew that you can use AWT in FX. Thank you so much!

Comment: JavaFX is missing(for now) some basic things for example(Robot and ImageIO) that AWT has.Generally try to avoid mixing these two cause they are running in different threads and may cause problems...Thats why i am using Platform.runLater in the example()..

Comment: @Slaw You can also use https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html